# sorting of string array

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to sort the string array in ascending order but I don't know exactly how to store the sorted elements into another string array.

below is the code:

```
String [] names= {"amazon", "apple", "facebook", "android", "sony"};
String[] sort= new String[names.length];

int i, j;
String temp=null;

for ( i = 0;  i < names.length - 1;  i++ ) {
    for ( j = i + 1;  j < names.length;  j++ ) {  
        if ( names [ i ].compareToIgnoreCase( names [ j ] ) > 0 ) {
           // ascending sort
           temp = names [ i ];
           names [ i ] = names [ j ];    // swapping
           names [ j ] = temp;                                            
        }                                                        
    } 
    sort [i]= names[j];                  
} 


for ( int k = 0;  k < names.length;  k++ )
    System.out.println( sort [ k ] );
}
```

Comment: *Please* take more effort to format your code before you post. It's extremely hard to read at the moment, and you could easily have seen that in the preview before you hit submit. Next, why don't you just copy the array (e.g. use `clone()`) and then use `Arrays.sort(copiedArray)`?

Comment: `if ( names [ i ].compareToIgnoreCase( names [ j ] ) < 0 )` ? But what about .sort methods?

Comment: Any particular reason not to use [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29)?

Comment: @fabian:  In **what universe** is this question a duplicate of that?

Comment: @fabian The statement of "how to store" is due to the failure of seeing the bug. Thus: no duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, so only pseudocode suggestion.

Requirement: Given a string array, return a sorted string array without changing order of information in the source string array.

Strategy: (create a function that does the sorting, and call that function

```
String [] sorted = sortMyArray(names);
```

1. Place input string array into a new string array
2. Sort the new string array (using appropriate algorithm)

Early in learning programming you can use the "interchange" sort (like you have done). However, you should research faster algorithms for larger arrays (e.g. bubble sort) and implement that in the sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = { "amazon", "apple", "facebook", "android", "sony" };
    String[] sort = new String[names.length];


    int i, j;
    String temp = null;

    for (i = 0; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
        //added a negative 1 to names.length
        for (j = i + 1; j < names.length - 1; j++) {
            if (names[i].compareToIgnoreCase(names[j]) > 0) { // ascending
                //swap works fine here                                              // sort
                temp = names[i];
                names[i] = names[j]; // swapping
                names[j] = temp;

            }

        }
        //removed this 
        //sort[i] = names[j -i];

    }
    //added this to copy the name array to the sort array ...however this isn't really needed
    for(int s = 0; s < names.length; s++){
        sort[s] = names[s];
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < names.length; k++)
        System.out.println(sort[k]);
}
```

I changed some of your code there ... you pretty much had it.  if you know how to use the debugger in eclipse finding the errors should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] names = {"amazon", "apple", "facebook", "android", "sony"};
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(names));
        String[] sort = new String[names.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) {
                if ((names[i].trim().compareToIgnoreCase(names[j].trim())) > 0) {
                    String temp = names[i];
                    names[i] = names[j]; 
                    names[j] = temp;

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(names));
```

or

```
Arrays.sort(names);
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple logic error:

```
 sort [i]= names[j];
```

must be rewritten as

```
 sort [i]= names[i];
```

Clearly, storing the result into another array is redundant, because the algorithm sorts the original array. To keep this as it was: copy and sort the copy.

Comment: Unfortunately with only this change the original array and the new array are both sorted. The requirement appears to be to leave the original array unchanged.

Comment: Well, out of the answers, you're *closer*, but there's one more bug you missed.

Comment: @Makoto Bah. Fix it, don't make clever remarks. He did show code, so get off your high horse.